# Configuring IIS Express to use default ports for http and https for debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, ssl, iis-express

I have followed [scot's article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) on how to enable default ports (80 and 443) for http and https respectively. I have followed each step to the letter and in the end IIS express sytem tray shows me that site is running on following urls

[image]

Only thing i have done differently is to use `netsh>advfirewall>firewall` context because it was telling me that `netsh firewall` is deprecated. I used following command to allow port 80 through firewall

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 80" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
```

Here is the relevant site section from applicationhost.config file of IIS Express

```
<site name="SSLTest" id="4">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="G:\Adeel\SSLTest\SSLTest" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51518:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44301:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:mhlabs" />
                  <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:mhlabs" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

**Edit:** The problem is that when i browse to http:/mhlabs or https:/mhlabs it does not work. I get not found page of the browser. how can i get around that.
**Edit2:** Ok, as a first step, i would like to forget ssl and just reserve a url for test-one on port 80 and run my site on this url. The logical steps that come to mind is that i reserve a url using `netsh http add urlacl url=http://test-one:80/ user=everyone` and add this entry in bindings section of applicationhost.config file. i also allowed port 80 through firewall but the whole thing does not seem to work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: I have turned off the firewall but still, i can't access site through friendly url like `http://mhlabs` and `https://mhlabs`

Answer (score 4):

Are you starting iis express from command line or using WebMatrix?

If you are not starting it from command line, try following steps and see if there are any binding errors.

1. start command prompt, goto iis express installation folder '%programfiles%\iis express'
2. run following command

   iisexpress.exe /site:SSLTest
3. If there are any bindings registration failure, you would see some error message.
   If there is any error for 'mhlabs' binding registration, make sure your URL reservation is correct. URL reservation command should like below

   netsh http add urlacl url=http://mhlabs:80/ user=everyone

Comment: iis express is automatically started by vs 2010 because i am using iis express for debugging rather than its built in dev server.

Comment: and also i have reserved the url with netsh http add urlacl command and if i try to add it again it gives error saying file exists or like that. i can paste exact detail on Monday.

Comment: can you try to start it from command line and see if there is any bindings failure error message?